# How to write Junit to test catch block

Tags: junit

I have to write Junit for below method. How i can cover catch block with Junit
using @Test(expected = SQLException.class).

```
public int getId(final String col1, final int col2,
            String col3) throws DatabaseDownException {

        final String IdQuery = "Select id from Manager where col1= ? and col2 = ? and col3 = ?";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        int Id = 0;
        try {
            con = getDataSource().getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(IdQuery);
            stmt.setString(1, col1);
            stmt.setInt(2, col2);
            stmt.setString(3, col3);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (null != rs && rs.next()) {
                Id = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("ERROR-WARNING:<<<getId():: ID "+col1+" SQLException occurred while selecting data table.");

        } finally {
            cleanUp(rs, stmt, con);
        }


        return Id;

    }
```

Comment: you want to know SQLException was thrown and catch inside method? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676860/test-if-an-exception-is-caught-with-junit

Comment: i want to cover catch block in junit. like i want to pass value to this method so that it throws SQLException. Which i will check in Junit test method, like @Test(expected = SQLException.class). Just want to cover exception scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an inner method from the code inside try block (refactor extract method) that both JUnit test and your method will use:

```
protected int getId(final String col1, final int col2, String col3, final String IdQuery, int Id) throws SQLException {
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        con = getDataSource().getConnection();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(IdQuery);
        stmt.setString(1, col1);
        stmt.setInt(2, col2);
        stmt.setString(3, col3);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (null != rs && rs.next()) {
            Id = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        return Id;
    }
```

Unit test:

```
@Test(expected = SQLException.class)
public void testGetId() {
   getId(...)
}
```

Comment: what parameter to pass in getId() so that SQLException occur and testGetId() pass.

Comment: @Arpan Paliwal you should decide what you want to check, the easiest is to put invalid query as `sele` in `IdQuery` parameter

Comment: I cannot change getId method and can not pass query, i can just pass col1,col2,col3 value from test method, how these parameter create invalid query. Please see my method signature.

Comment: @ArpanPaliwal If you can't change it, try sending null in `col1` parmeter